# Dynamically reference eConnect dll and create an array of instances with the invoke method

Tags: c#, dll

i'm looking to create an array of instances using the invoke method on a constructor in a runtime referenced dll. I have to do this because I am changing which dll's are referenced based on settings chosen by the user.

Here is the code that isn't working

```
Type IVItemMasterType = EConSerialAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization.IVItemMasterType");
                    ConstructorInfo IVItemMasterConstructor = IVItemMasterType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);

                    object IV = null;

                    object[] IVItemMaster = null;
                    if(IVItemMasterConstructor != null)
                    {
                        IV = IVItemMasterConstructor.Invoke(new object[0]);

                        IVItemMaster = IVItemMasterConstructor.Invoke(new object[0])[1];

                        if (IV != null)
                        {
                            //good
                           IVItemMaster[0] = IV;
                        }
                    }
```

I want to create an array of instances as the IVItemMaster but i don't know how to create an array of instances with the invoke method

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

use the `array.createinstance` method

This method has two parameters:

param 1 = `Type (use your IVItemMasterType here)`
param 2 = `array size`

So, instantiate a dynamic object called `IVItemMasters` and then reference this object like `IVItemMasters[count] = a single instance of the IVItemMaster Type`

I hope this works.